# Can we remove the calendar icon from the TextField (MUI)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

Here is my basic code to accomplish the task, but couldn't come up with any outcome

```js
 <TextField
        sx={{
          '&::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator': {
            display: 'none',
            '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
          },
        }}
        id="outlined-basic"
        variant="outlined"
        type="date"
        helperText="Please select the date"
      />
```

Also, I did a bit research on InputProps (endAdornment) within TextField to remove the icon, but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the exact implementation  of TextField from material-ui and not a customization? Can you share in a [runnable example in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react)?

Comment: Hey @OluwafemiSule, thanks for the response. I think Akis and Tamas answer helped me to get a hang of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You can define in the components property the icon to be null for both cases.

```
<TimePicker
      label="Time"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      disableOpenPicker
    />
    <DateTimePicker
      label="Date&Time picker"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      disableOpenPicker
    />
```

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-demo-mui-x-forked-tto73y?file=/demo.tsx:879-1432)

Comment: Thanks @akis. This fixed the issue, but the typescript is complaining that OpenPickerIcon can be React.ElementType<any> | undefined. Setting the value to undefined does not remove the icon. Any word of advise?

Comment: Hi @user2824374 I just updated the sandbox and now Typescript is not complaining. What i did is to replace with "OpenPickerIcon: 'null' as undefined" which passes but I am not sure if is the best approach for Typescript. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Akis. I just realized there is another props that we can use "disableOpenPicker" to remove the icon as well :)

Comment: Thanks @user2824374 I will update my answer the soonest possible for future users

Answer (score 0):

I guess u r using MUIv5

(and I guess u talking about DatePicker)

In that case (as u mentioned), the icon is rendered cuz the `InputProps` with `endAdornment` is passed to the text field, if u omit that prop, there will be no icon.

```
<DatePicker
   label="Basic example"
   value={value}
   onChange={(newValue) => {
       setValue(newValue);
   }}
   renderInput={({ InputProps, ...props }) => (
       <TextField {...props} />
   )}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped. I'm trying to mimic the same for TimePicker with TextField  having No AM/PM, 24 hr format, and remove Icon. This is the code I've attempted. No help.

`
 <TimePicker
        ampm={false}
        value={value}
        openTo="hours"
        mask="__:__:__"
        inputFormat="HH:mm:ss"
        views={["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={({ props }) => (
          <TextField type="time" inputProps={{ step: 1 }} {...props} />
        )}
      />`